# When creating a chrome extension should API calls be made from the background script or front-end?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that requires an HTTP Get Request API call whenever a new page loads. My extension then inserts an IFrame in the web page, to which I would like to provide the data from the API call. I have devised two different ways of doing this. I have been able to get both ways to work, however, I am wondering which is more advisable.

1. After the content script injects the iframe it makes a call to a background script. In the background script, we fetch the data and do message passing with the `postMessage` function to send the data to the IFrame. The data is then received by a script inside the IFrame and the data is loaded.
2. After the content script injects the iframe a script runs inside the IFrame that fetches the data. This same script then loads the data.

Or if there are any other methods, I would be grateful for any recommendations. My logic as of now comparing the two methods I have described is that the first method has advantages of conducting the API calls from the backgorund script, while the second method has the advantage of not requireing a large amount of communication between various scripts.

Is either of these methods superior? Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any extension page or frame that has a `chrome-extension://` URL has equal rights. It includes iframes that you insert in web pages with `src` pointing to an html file from your extension exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in manifest.json.

It means there are no inherent restrictions or preferred methods.
It only depends on the life cycle of data.

When it would make sense to make the request in the background page:

- to cache it in a variable/object if you have a persistent background page for whatever reason;
- to avoid interruption of the request due to the tab being closed or navigated away by the user or the main document's script;
- to transform the data using some library that you load in the background script and don't want to load it in the UI page/frame for whatever reason e.g. it's slow to load.
- any other reason.

As for sharing between pages it should be fast even with messaging unless your data exceeds 64MB message size limit in which case you would have to use `Blob` URLs or directly access the variable via [getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage) that returns the `window` object of the background script. There's also [BroadcastChannel](https://devdocs.io/dom/broadcastchannel) API that should be able to work between all chrome-extension:// page or frames of an extension and in Chrome it should be much faster than messaging thanks to using the *structured cloning* algorithm instead of JSON stringify/parsing used by messaging internally.

As a rule of thumb for any performance-related concerns: use devtools performance profiler.

Comment: Is the BroadcastChannel API different than Window.postMessage?

Comment: The transport is the same but the API has a different surface.